# Background not showing, using external css

Tags: html

I'm making an landing page for school.

## Register Here !!!!

**First name:**
            
            **Last name:**
            
            **Birthday:**
            
            **Contact Number:**
            
            **Address:**
            
            **Email :**
            
            
            Male
            
            Female
            
            Other
            
            Submit
          
        
       
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
    
    html, body{
        
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .back  {
      /* The image used */
      background-image:url("front2.png");
    
     
      min-height: 100px;
    
      
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that CSS file linked properly then Check your Image url. If it's ok then make `.back` class height fixed pixel. like.. `Height: 450px;`.

Answer (score 0):

may be also the path of your image is not good , if your image is in image folder you have to do background-image:url("image/front2.png");